# Spring Data JPA Optional handling

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have such a query in a project:

```
@Query("FROM UserDataEntity ud " +
            "JOIN FETCH ud.userDepartments userDep " +
            "JOIN FETCH userDep.department WHERE ud.userId = :userId")
    Optional<UserDataEntity> findByUserIdWithDepartments(Long userId);
```

JPA spec says (EJB 3.0 persistency, paragraph 4.4.5.3 “Fetch Joins”) that parent relation in FETCH JOIN statement is duplicated, i.e if I rewrite the repository method to return
`List<UserDataEntity> findByUserIdWithDepartments(Long userId)` there will be 2 references to the same UserDataEntity if it has 2 child departments.
In my understanding there should be a runtime exception (Optional awaits for a single result to be returned). But everything works fine. How does Spring Data handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would use a custom query here, why not let Spring Data magic work for you with smart naming and simply calling the getter on the relation that is lazy loaded:

```
// In your repository you have this (if you are sure that userId is unique) which will be implemnted by JPA
Optional<UserDataEntity> findByUserId(Long userId);

// In you service
UserDataEntity userDatEntity = userDataRepository.findByUserId(userId).orElseThrow();
userDatEntity.getUserDepartments;
...
```

Keep in mind that all entity relations should be lazy loaded and when you need these relations, you just call the getters.